# How to authenticate Websocket connections in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket

I have an HTML application.

Some pages have to run websockets to connect to a server running an Asp.Net application and send/receive some messages through Websocket.

The websockets server works fine. But anyone can send some requests to the server. I would like my server to be protected and receives only authenticated requests. For example from Javascript in Developer Mode, I can run requests against Websocket server...

So far I'm accepting requests only from my domain as follows but that is not enough :

```
    var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions()
    {
        KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
    };
    webSocketOptions.AllowedOrigins.Add("https://example.com");
    webSocketOptions.AllowedOrigins.Add("https://www.example.com");

    app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
```

Is there any way to authenticate Websocket requests ? Or for example allow only legitimate users send requests to the WS server ?

Thanks.

Comment: At a protocol level, web sockets start with a http request, then negotiate to keep the connection open and use it as a socket. You should be able to authenticate the http request headers first, before creating the web socket. Either with your own middleware that runs first, or by copying the implementation and tweaking it (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Middleware/WebSockets/src/WebSocketMiddleware.cs)

Comment: Hmmmm, digging into the details further, does you code look like this sample? https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8b30d862de6c9146f466061d51aa3f1414ee2337/src/Middleware/WebSockets/samples/EchoApp/Startup.cs#L43 So somewhere you are calling `.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync`? Then you have complete control over validating the request at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone else could provide more information - as I am not very familiar with WS(Web Sockets), but here what I would do (number 3 is probably what you want):

1. Validate Before WS connection is established - Self explanatory, don't create a WS connection if they had not authenticated via another method, but that's not always the option;
2. Use a specified format with a validation built it - Lets say the socket is expecting a message in the form of:

   {
   "Token": "27e0127341dfaojo",
   "Message": "Hello World!",
   "Command": "SendMessage"
   }

If it is not in that format, then ignore it - and once it is, you can validate the token.

3. Using  ([Cookie Authentication](https://coletiv.com/blog/using-websockets-with-cookie-based-authentication/)) - the link explains more.